# How could Banner's gamma radiation exposure be both an accident and a self-experiment?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk-2008, hulk-2003

In *The Hulk* (2003) movie it was shown that gamma exposure was an accident. However, in subsequent movies it was portrayed as self experimentation, so which theory is true?

Comment: @Gnemlock if it's self-experimentation, exposure is not an accident..?

Comment: Deliberate exposure does not mean you don't e.g. get a larger dose by accident than you intended.  Not sure if that's relevant to that particular movie, but as a general rule these things are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 11):

*The Hulk* (2003) and *The Incredible Hulk* (2008) movies don't share a common universe (*The Incredible Hulk* is a reboot, not sequel). So, don't expect consistency.